# Getting error while accessing internal enum from public enum in swift 4.2

Tags: swift, enums, xcode10, objective-c-swift-bridge

I am getting error while accessing *internal* enum values inside *public* enum

**Code snippet**

```
@objc public enum Sample1 : Int {
      case valid
      fileprivate static var upgradeStatus:[String: Sample1] = [
          RawString.validValue.rawValue : .valid
      ]
}

internal enum RawString: String {
    case validValue = "Invalid"
}
```

**The error says**

```
Enum 'RawString' is internal and cannot be referenced from a property initializer in a '@_fixed_layout' type
```

Looks like it is because of bridging ***@Objc*** but not able to fix the issue. I cannot remove **@Objc** as my code is used in Objective C project as well.

Could anyone please help me in resolving this issue.

**P.S** : Started observing this error once after I update to **Xcode 10**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert `upgradeStatus` to a static method, this will make your code compile:

```
fileprivate static func upgradeStatus() -> [String: Sample1] {
    return [
        RawString.validValue.rawValue : .valid
    ]
}
```